# Output three nxn tables

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code where I put a number n in input() and in output I will get three same nxn tables. I cannot use if's nor '\t' nor lists. I am only a begginer so we cannot use any difficult functions or anything like that.

This is my code:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(f'{i*n + j + 1:2}', end=' ')
    for k in range(n):
        print(f'{i*n + k + 1:2}', end=' ')
    for l in range(n):
        print(f'{i*n + l + 1:2}', end=' ')
    print()
```

The problem is that I need to put 4 whitespaces (a tab) behind every line of a table ( so that tables can be recognized as 3 and it doesn't look like one table).

My output looks like this now:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10  6  7  8  9 10  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 11 12 13 14 15 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 16 17 18 19 20 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 21 22 23 24 25 21 22 23 24 25
```

Output should look like this:

```
n: 5
 1  2  3  4  5     1  2  3  4  5     1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10     6  7  8  9 10     6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15    11 12 13 14 15    11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20    16 17 18 19 20    16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25    21 22 23 24 25    21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you finsh printing part of the line, mean after every for loop print some spaces:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(f'{i*n + j + 1:2}', end=' ')
    print('  ', end='')

    for j in range(n):
        print(f'{i*n + j + 1:2}', end=' ')
    print('  ', end='')

    for j in range(n):
        print(f'{i*n + j + 1:2}', end=' ')
    print('  ', end='')
    print()
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4  5    1  2  3  4  5    1  2  3  4  5   
 6  7  8  9 10    6  7  8  9 10    6  7  8  9 10   
11 12 13 14 15   11 12 13 14 15   11 12 13 14 15   
16 17 18 19 20   16 17 18 19 20   16 17 18 19 20   
21 22 23 24 25   21 22 23 24 25   21 22 23 24 25
```

and you can use the same name `j` in every loop it's not problem because here. because it will reinitialized by the for loop every time. Hope this is clear an simple for you.